# Dynamically change startAngle value in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I want to dynamically change the startAngle value on my polar chart from JSON 'Wind_direction' value.
The code is below:

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('wind_graph.php?callback=?', function(dataWind) {
    var direction = Wind_direction;
    var polarOptions = {
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      events : {
          load : function () {
              setInterval(function(){
                RefreshDataWind();
                }, 1000);
          }
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Wind Direction'
    },
    pane: {
      startAngle: direction,
    },
    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 15,
      min: 0,
      max: 360
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointStart: 0,
        pointInterval: 30,
      },
    }
  };

  // The polar chart
  $('#graph-1').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(polarOptions, {
    yAxis: {
      tickInterval: 5,
      min: 0,
      max: 25,
      visible: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Direction',
        data: [
          [0, 0],
          [direction, 20]
        ],
      }
    ]
  }));

  function RefreshDataWind()
  {
    var chart = $('#graph-1').highcharts();
    $.getJSON('wind_graph.php?callback=?', function(dataWind)
    {
        var direction = Wind_direction;
        chart.series[0].setData([[0,0],[direction, 20]]);
    }); 
  }
});
});
```

In the last function, below 'chart.series[0].setData... I was trying to add something like this:

```
chart.pane.setStartAngle(direction);
```

but this throws the error: "Cannot read property 'startAngle' of undefined"

Also was trying another one idea:

```
polarOptions.pane({ startAngle: direction });
```

but here is error: "polarOptions.pane is not a function".

So I'm stack. Please for help.

Comment: Have you tried: `polarOptions.pane.startAngle = 90` where 90 equals your value?

Comment: Nope. I've tryed now. There's nothing changing on the chart, only errors in console log disapeared.

Comment: Yes because you have to use the Chart.update() function to update the interface also. Check here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update all chart options with [Chart.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.update). Unfortunately, it looks that it does not have any effect on pane - I reported the issue [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6438).

Now you can update the pane in old-fashioned way - by destroying and creating a new chart - http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/qhY8C/

The other possibility is trying the workaround - set options for pane, remove the pane and update the axis - it should create a new pane with new options.

```
  const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
  chart.options.pane.startAngle = 45;
  Highcharts.erase(chart.panes, xAxis.pane);
  chart.yAxis[0].update(null, false);
  xAxis.update();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/v8L381Lj/